# Change Outlook signatures based on date

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I was wondering if it is possible to make Outlook change the default signature based on the date e.g. when it is 14th Feb, change the signature to a pre-made Valentine's Day one, when it is 25th Dec, make it a Christmas one?

Comment: What version of Outlook?

Comment: Preferably 2010, but this is more a general questions, so I don't mind if it's 07, 10 or 13

Comment: I think the VBA code changes based on the version of Outlook. That's why I asked.